# magento 2 migrating from local to live site. what is the host setting

Tags: magento2

i am migrating from my localhost to a live site. My question is, in the setting within the :

> app\etc\env.php

what is the setting for **'host'** . on the localhost the setting is **localhost**. but what about on a live site?

```
'db' => [
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'connection' => [
            'default' => [
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'dbname' => 'mydatabase',
                'username' => 'mydatabase',
                'password' => 'WWWWWNmpqkOv#JU0*',
                'active' => '1'
            ]
        ]
    ],
```

Comment: Hi @theSeeker no need to change the host name, just change 'dbname' => 'mydatabase',
                'username' => 'mydatabase',
                'password' => 'WWWWWNmpqkOv#JU0*',

Comment: it will be localhost only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which host is your database.

- Same server : localhost
- Different server : IP of the server or alias (your webserver needs to be able to resolve it)

Adjust db name, user and password according to your new host.